# Colorise printing of recipe commands

Tags: gnu-make

I would like to have the option to run the Makefile with/without a verbose mode and colorise the printing of the commands in the recipe.

After some researching I found that the typical way of achieving a "verbose mode" is by introducing a variable, `VERBOSE`, that can be set on the command line as shown in the example below.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

.PHONY: all hack

red = \033[31;1m
green = \033[32;1m
reset = \033[0m

VERBOSE ?= 0
export VERBOSE
AT_0 := @
AT_1 :=
AT    = $(AT_$(VERBOSE))

all:
    $(AT) printf '$(green)%s\n$(reset)' "GNU Is Not UNIX"

hack:
    @\
    if [[ $${VERBOSE} -eq 1 ]]; then \
      printf '$(red)%s\n$(reset)' "printf '$(green)%s\n$(reset)' \"GNU Is Not UNIX\""; \
    fi; \
    printf '$(green)%s\n$(reset)' "GNU Is Not UNIX"
```

As yo can see one can now optionally display key commands in a recipe:

```
usr@cmptr $ make
GNU Is Not UNIX
usr@cmptr $ make VERBOSE=1
printf '\033[32;1m%s\n\033[0m' "GNU Is Not UNIX"
GNU Is Not UNIX
```

Now back to the beginning. Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can modify this approach such that it also colors the command of the recipe *without* modifying the color of the output of the command itself?

The desired result is displayed int the `hack` target

```
usr@cmptr $ make VERBOSE=1 hack
printf '\033[32;1m%s\n\033[0m' "GNU Is Not UNIX"
GNU Is Not UNIX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the best way of handling verbose modes.  Take a look at http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/

The output that you're suppressing by adding `@` at the beginning is printed by make, it's not printed by the shell.  There's no way to get make to colorize its output (short of editing the source code for make).

If you want to see the command colorized you'll have to print it out yourself.  If you do that, you'll want to use the `@` literally all the time, and not allow it to be overridden via `VERBOSE` or whatever.  Your rules will all have to have the format:

```
foo:
        @ printf '$(green)%s$(reset)\n' 'my command'; my command
```

If you want verbose mode AS WELL, so that unless you enable it it won't print the command, you have to combine these.  One option would be to use a macro you can call, like this:

```
ifeq ($(VERBOSE),)
    run = @ $1
else
    run = @ printf '$(green)%s$(reset)\n' '$(subst ','\'',$1)'; $1
endif

foo:
        $(call run,my command)
```

Note that if `my command` could contain commas you'll have to hide those from make.